# how to correctly use base64 from another file

Tags: html, css, image, refactoring, html-email

I would like to explain my problem of the day

currently i am in an html file and i am using an img in it

I reduced the size of the base64 to not spam ^^

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAACWCAIAAACzY+a1AAAMQGlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAASImVVwdYU8kWnluSkEBoAQSkhN4EkRpASggtgPQiiEpIAoQSYyCo2JFFBdeCigjY0FURxQ6IBUXsLIq9LxZUlHWxYFfepICu+8r3zvfNvf/958x/zpw7twwAasc5IlEOqg5ArjBfHBPsTx+flEwnPQUIQAEZEACdw80TMaO"
style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 75px; height: 75px; margin-bottom: 
20px; margin-top: 20px;"width="100"
alt="icon"
/>
```

so my problem and the following the link of my base64 and really super super long

I would like to find a solution to reduce this part? maybe extract the base64 and put it in another file?

something like that?

```
<img
    src="data:image/png;base64,/image.txt"
    width="75"
    height="75"
    alt="icon"
    />
```

except it doesn't work

if you have any ideas, thank you

Neff